# Execute application when paste is clicked in Windows (explorer)

Tags: c#

I have an application, which basically is a copier, but it can do much more other stuff. What I can't get past is this:

I want to open the application when the user selected a few files (in explorer, desktop, or anywhere in Windows), and all those selected files, should be in the cache or something like that so that it is in a list or something.

This is done by Windows, so I don't have to do that. When the user selected all of the files he wanted to select, and copied it, how do I execute the application when the user pastes that files somewhere else? So that it automatically opens?

I have this:

```
[DllImport("User32.dll")]
protected static extern int
SetClipboardViewer(int hWndNewViewer);
[DllImport("User32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
public static extern bool
ChangeClipboardChain(IntPtr hWndRemove,
IntPtr hWndNewNext);
[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
public static extern int SendMessage(IntPtr hwnd, int wMsg,
IntPtr wParam,
IntPtr lParam);

IntPtr nextClipboardViewer;


protected override void WndProc(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m)
{
    // Defined in winuser.h
    const int WM_DRAWCLIPBOARD = 0x308;
    const int WM_CHANGECBCHAIN = 0x030D;

    switch (m.Msg)
    {
        case WM_DRAWCLIPBOARD:
            DisplayClipboardData();
            SendMessage(nextClipboardViewer, m.Msg, m.WParam, m.LParam);
            break;

        case WM_CHANGECBCHAIN:
            if (m.WParam == nextClipboardViewer)
            {
                nextClipboardViewer = m.LParam;
            }
            else
            {
                SendMessage(nextClipboardViewer, m.Msg, m.WParam,
                m.LParam);
            }
            break;

        default:
            base.WndProc(ref m);
            break;
    }
}

void DisplayClipboardData()
{
    try
    {
        IDataObject iData = new DataObject();
        iData = Clipboard.GetDataObject();
        if (iData.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.Rtf))
        {
            richTextBox1.Rtf = (string)iData.GetData(DataFormats.Rtf);
        }
        else if (iData.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.Text))
        {
            richTextBox1.Text = (string)iData.GetData(DataFormats.Text);
        }
        else
        {
            richTextBox1.Text = "[Clipboard data is not RTF or ASCII Text]";
        }


    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(e.ToString());
    }
}
```

But this only works when text is selected. How can I display the file directory of each file?

Comment: Before a user can paste (CTRL + V), he first has to Cut (CTRL + X) or Copy (CTRL + C). Are you sure you want to react an the paste and not on the cut or copy?

Comment: Which would then be the best? Either way would then be fine. So then if the user copies, all those file directories should then be in a list in the application. That would actually work better, yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to react on the copy (Ctrl+C) or cut (Ctrl+V) operation rather than the paste (Ctrl+V) operation, it is actually relatively simple.
All you have to do is monitor the clipboard, because that's where this information goes. The data format you have to listen for is `FileDrop`.

Unfortunatelly, you will have to use the WinAPI to listen for clipboard changes.

When you received such a change, you can retrieve the list of copied files like this:

```
void DisplayClipboardData()
{
    if(!Clipboard.ContainsFileDropList())
        return;

    var fileList = Clipboard.GetFileDropList();
    // Do something with the file list.
}
```

Comment: @Bebbie7: As I said, you need to check for FileDrop. You are currently checking for Rtf and Text. Change the `DisplayClipboardData` to only check for `DataFormats.FileDrop`.

Comment: OH! Sorry that is my bad. Thanx! I got this up and running now:).

Comment: How would I find the file sizes of the files in fileList?

Comment: For example using the `FileInfo` class: http://www.dotnetperls.com/fileinfo-length

Comment: So FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(filename);

Comment: And that is displayed in bits?

Comment: @Bebbie7: Really, this has nothing to do with either your original question or this answer. And this information is readily available in the documentation and even in the link I gave you. Please use your own head first.

Comment: Do you know how to get the "paste" event. User can choose to right click > paste instead of ctrl+v. How to listen for paste? Hooking GetClipboardData didn't work because it is called on right click and again on Paste. Where do I look?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to do 2 things:

1) Hook up to the windows keyboard & mouse events using the [SetWindowsHookEx](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.setwindowshookex), here is [an example](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14485/Low-level-Windows-API-hooks-from-C-to-stop-unwante) in a winform application

2) [check the clipboard's contents](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c2thcsx4%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) and do what you need with them

The main thing for this approach is that the hook which you would listen for keyboard events must be associated with a thread, so your application has to be already loaded up and remain resident in memory for you receive the events. You can create a limited gui and have an [icon in the system trey](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/27599/Minimize-window-to-system-tray) maybe.

**Edit**: [MSDN overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644959%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#wh_keyboard_llhook) on windows hooks